# Cross post type parent page added parent page to permalink but give 404

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks, hierarchical

I have made some custom post types with Magicfields. I need to set the parent page for a custom post type to a standard wordpress page.  Figured that out with the help of this: http://janina.tumblr.com/post/3588081423/post-parent-different-type

But now the parent page and it's parent is being added to the permalink and the view page or the new URL is returning a 404.

Example:

- Custom Post Type Products light and post x-rays
- Set Parent of x-rays Product Page to waves Page which is a standard WP Page and has a parent of science
- this creates this URL site.com/light/science/waves/x-rays - this breaks
- without a parent for x-rays, the URL is site.com/light/x-rays
- with the cross post type parent - the science/waves is added and view page gives 404, but if I removed the /science/waves from the URL, the site.com/light/x-rays works.

So it seems the permalink structure doesn't know how to go from one post type to another.  Which makes the get_permalink function not work, which causes all kinds of headaches.

Suggestions, questions?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need only to change the way `get_permalink` create url for the cpt, ignoring the parent.

You can do it adding a filter to `'post_type_link'` hook and then *regenerate* the permalink for the product cpt in the same way is done in core, just ignoring the parent:

```
add_filter('post_type_link', 'reset_light_link', 999, 3);

function reset_light_link( $post_link, $post, $leavename ) {
  if ( $post->post_type != 'light' || in_array($post->post_status, array('draft','pending','auto-draft')) ) return $post_link;
  global $wp_rewrite;
  $post_link = $wp_rewrite->get_extra_permastruct($post->post_type);
  if ( ! $leavename ) $post_link = str_replace("%$post->post_type%", $post->post_name, $post_link);
  return home_url( user_trailingslashit($post_link) );
}
```

The code for `reset_light_link` function is just a modded version of [`get_post_permalink`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_permalink), the function used in core to generate the permalink (and that fires the `'post_type_link'` hook) when `get_permalink` is called for a cpt.

[**Here**](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/branches/3.6/wp-includes/link-template.php#L178) the code for that function.